# Validation of a Simple Form

Tags: javascript

In process of learning JS. Trying to learn how to loop through an entire form, and have errors pointed out.

This is a hodgepodge that I cobbled together from various tutorials online.

Clearly it's not working.

What I am trying to do is to get the forms' entire collection of its elements, and loop through it, and anything that's blank, to have its error message printed somewhere on the same screen, be it above the form or underneath the textboxes itself.

This is what I have so far. Any help in getting this to work, or at least the concept of what I outlined? Simple and bite-size explanations if possible would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
         <div id="validation"></div>
         <p><label>Name<br><input type="text" name="Name"></label></p>
         <p><label>Email<br><input type="text" name="Email"></label></p>
         <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
      </form>
      <script>
         var formsCollection = document.forms[0]; 
         for (var i = 0; i < formsCollection.elements.length; i++) {
             if (formsCollection.elements.value.length == 0) {
                 form.elements.input.border = "1px solid red"; 
                 form.Name.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
             }
             return true;
         }
         document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function () {
             return Validate(this);
         };
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

EDIT

```
<script>
  function Validate() {
     var formsCollection = document.forms[0]; 
     for (var i = 0; i < formsCollection.elements.length; i++) {
         if (formsCollection.elements[i].value.length == 0) {
             form.elements.input.border = "1px solid red"; 
             form.Name.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
         }
         return true;
     }
     document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function () {
         return Validate(this);
     };
 }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full ans:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>
  <form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
     <div id="validation"></div>
     <p><label>Name<br><input type="text" name="Name"></label></p>
     <p><label>Email<br><input type="text" name="Email"></label></p>
     <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
  </form>

<script>
 document.forms[0].onsubmit= function() {
     var form = document.forms[0];
     for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
         if (form.elements[i].value.length == 0) {
               console.log(form.elements[i]);
             form.elements[i].border = "1px solid red"; 
             form.elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FFCCCC";
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
 </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

Several problems.

1. There seems to be no `i` in your for loop usage.

Try `if (formsCollection.elements.value.length == 0) {`
to `if (formsCollection.elements[i].value.length == 0) {`

2. Where is your `Validate` function?

Wrap `var formsCollection ... END_OF_FOR_LOOP` with `function Validate(){` and `}`

Comment: I put in the changes as you suggested in the `EDIT` part ... still not working ... any ideas why?

Comment: @user273072545345 Let me have a look. Plz wait.

Comment: @user273072545345 It takes me 15minutes to do it and finally it works. Plz choose me as the right answer and give me a upvote. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your time in answering it. Answer has been accepted. Quick question though. Is there a way to have all the fields that are blank show that right away instead of one at a time as per this script?

Comment: @user273072545345 remove the `return false`. Could you plz give me a **upvote**? Thanks.

Comment: sure, happy to upvote always.  FYI, removed the false statement, but it's very brief the red highlighting of both elements in the form. Just wanted to let you know. But thank you for helping me to get started on this.